# Highlight a selected row in ListView for Android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have created a listView set of rows which I have managed to alternate the colours successfully.

However, I want to be able to change the colour of the row once the user has selected one.

I have set my XML as follows:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
```

My full java code is below:

```
public class Task2Activity extends ListActivity {

ListView list;
String [] dogTitles;
String [] dogDescriptions;
String [] dogToastDescriptions;
int[] images = {R.drawable.husky, R.drawable.pug, R.drawable.yorkshire_terrier, R.drawable.french_bulldog,
R.drawable.border_collie, R.drawable.great_dane, R.drawable.staffordshire_bull_terrier, R.drawable.golden_retriever,
R.drawable.german_shepherd, R.drawable.doberman};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_task2);

    Resources res = getResources();
    dogTitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    dogDescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
    dogToastDescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.toastdescriptions);



    //list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    dogAdapter <String> adapter = new dogAdapter<String>(this, dogTitles, images, dogDescriptions) {
        //list.

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (position %2 == 1)
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e6e9ef"));
            }
            else
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c9d0db"));
            }
            return view;

        }
    };

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        }

   @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

   MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
   menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_context_menu, menu);

}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

    String item = dogToastDescriptions[position];


       Toast.makeText(this, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getListView().setSelected(true);


       }

class dogAdapter<S> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
int[] images;
String[] titleArray;
String[] descriptionArray;

dogAdapter(Context c, String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] desc) {
    super(c, R.layout.single_row, R.id.largeText, titles);
    this.context = c;
    this.images = imgs;
    this.titleArray = titles;
    this.descriptionArray = desc;
}

class MyViewHolder {
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView myTitle;
    TextView myDescription;

    MyViewHolder(View v) {
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.largeText);
        myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.smallText);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        Log.d("dogs", "Creating a new row");
    } else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
        Log.d("dogs", "Recycling stuff");
    }
    //ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    //TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.largeText);
    //TextView myDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.smallText);

    holder.myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    holder.myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
    holder.myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);

    return row;
}

}
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  Many thanks

Comment: Do you got the answer?

Answer (score 3):

In onListItemClick() you can set the color of the selected item:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

    String item = dogToastDescriptions[position];

    v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_green_light));//your color here

    Toast.makeText(this, item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    getListView().setSelected(true);

}
```

There is also an option in the Listview, that highlights selected values :

```
  <ListView android:id="@+id/my_listView"
     android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
     android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" <!--your color here -->
   />
```

android:choiceMode = "singleChoice" is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for this.  It does work in that it highlights the row I click on but it stays highlighted when I click on another one.  In other words, I keep clicking on rows and it continues to highlight them.  I want it to be able to highlight one and then go off and highlight another one when I click on another.  Thanks

Comment: @PhilAdams, you should store the position of the last clicked fragment that was highlighted and change that back to the original colour, then change the newly selected item to the highlighted colour.

Comment: @BradleyWilson Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not quite sure how to do it but I'll look it up and give it a go

Comment: so you could store it inside SharedPreferences, as a key "previousItem" or something, and store the position of the clicked item onListItemClick, but before you store it, check if it a previousItem exists in sharedPreferences if it does change the position corresponding to the int stored, if there isn't one store the new position for the next time the user clicks (if that makes sense)